# regular expression to remove hidden fields

Tags: .net, regex

I have written the following regular expression to remove viewstate hidden fields from html

```
Regex.Replace(html, "<input[^>]*id=\"__VIEWSTATE\"[^>]*>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

How can I modify this to include, __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT, __EVENTVALIDATION in the regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(html, "<input[^>]*id=\"(__VIEWSTATE|__EVENTTARGET|__EVENTARGUMENT|__EVENTVALIDATION)\"[^>]*>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Easily understandable and extendable.

Answer (score 0):

You could add all the items to a list, and then iterate through them like this:

```
var items = new List { "__VIEWSTATE", "__EVENTTARGET", "__EVENTARGUMENT", "__EVENTVALIDATION" };

foreach (item in items) {
    Regex.Replace(html, string.format("<input[^>]*id=\"{0}\"[^>]*>", item), string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

I find this code easier to understand if I came across it in code, as opposed to a collection of OR'd statements.

Answer (score 0):

`"<input[^>]*id=\"__(?:VIEWSTATE|(?:EVENT(?:TARGET|ARGUMENT|VALIDATION)))\"[^>]*>"`